# How to handle when there is no react from server nodejs?

Tags: node.js, ajax

I'm beginner node.js 
when i already check my server open but 
there is no reaction when i try to open my index.html 
i made directory just nothing react why this happend? 
DBtestApp > ajax_test > www > index.html 
and i saved my nodejs setting in DBtestApp 
but when i access port 3000 
just show me 'Express
Welcome to Express'
how can i check opeating my index.html

I already check the server open when i access http://localhost:3000/ 
the page show to me 'Express welcome to express' but i don't understand why index.html didn't open

**This is my index.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf8">
        <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>



     $(document).ready(function(){

            $('#ButtonRequest').click(function(){

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://localhost:3000/Echo',
                    data:{
                        myData: "Hello",
                    },
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    success: function(data){
                        console.log(data);
                        $('.Response').text('answer from server  : '+data.result);
                    },
                    error: function(){
                        $('.Response').text('error occured');
                    }
                });

            });

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="Response"></div>
    <input type="button" id="ButtonRequest" value="AJAX start" />

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**This is my setting nodejs ajax_srv_test.js**

```
var express = require('express'); 
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 
var path = require('path');

// Path setting 
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'ajax_test', 'www')));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

// service main page return 
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'ajax_test', 'www', 'index.html'));
});

// Echo service
app.get('/Echo', function(req, res){
    var callbackName = req.query.callback;
    var myData = req.query.myData;
    var ResObj = {};
    ResObj.result = myData;
    var server = app.listen(3000, function(){
        console.log("Express server has started on port 3000");
    });
    res.header('Content-type','application/json');
    res.header('Charset','utf8');
    res.send(callbackName + '('+JSON.stringify(ResObj)+');');

});
```

and when i write in terminal

```
node ajax_srv_test
```

there is no reaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for starting the server is within `/Echo` route and that is the reason it is never executed resulting into HTTP server not being started. Please change the code for `/Echo` route to something as below:

```
// Echo service
app.get('/Echo', function(req, res){
    var callbackName = req.query.callback;
    var myData = req.query.myData;
    var ResObj = {};
    ResObj.result = myData;    
    res.header('Content-type','application/json');
    res.header('Charset','utf8');
    res.send(callbackName + '('+JSON.stringify(ResObj)+');');

});

var server = app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Express server has started on port 3000");
});
```

Comment: Ah im sorry ! im begginer stackoverflow too 
just i marked your answer 
thank your so much